# How to fetch a value from database to javascript code in view file (laravel 5.2)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass a variable from my controller file to javascript code in my view file, which i have fetched from database using a sql query in controller, it is in a variable, i can pass that variable to view file using simple laravel method but unable to use it in javascript code may be because of its scope.

My view file:

```
<div id="js-example-disabled">
    <h2><code>Mood Meter..!!</code></h2>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="50" data-rangeSlider disabled>
    <output></output>

    <button data-behaviour="toggle">@if($user==Auth::user())<p>Change Mood</p>@endif</button>

</div>
<div id="j">

</div>


<script src="{{URL::asset('rangeSlider.js')}}"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        var value;

        var selector = '[data-rangeSlider]',
                elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

        // Example functionality to demonstrate a value feedback
        function valueOutput(element) {
            value = element.value,
                    output = element.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('output')[0];

        }

        for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            valueOutput(elements[i]);
        }

        Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]')).forEach(function (el) {
            el.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
                valueOutput(e.target);
            }, false);
        });


        // Example functionality to demonstrate disabled functionality
        var toggleBtnDisable = document.querySelector('#js-example-disabled button[data-behaviour="toggle"]');
        toggleBtnDisable.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            var inputRange = toggleBtnDisable.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
            console.log(inputRange);
            if (inputRange.disabled) {
                inputRange.disabled = false;
            }
            else {
                inputRange.disabled = true;
            }
            inputRange.rangeSlider.update();
        }, false);
        rangeSlider.create(elements, {

value:10,
            // Callback function
            onInit: function () {
            },

            // Callback function
            onSlideStart: function (value) {
                console.info('onSlideStart', 'value: ' + value);
            },

            // Callback function
            onSlide: function (value) {
                console.log('onSlide', 'value: ' + value);
            },

            // Callback function
            onSlideEnd: function (value) {
                 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('j').innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "/meter/"+value, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
            }
        });

    })();

</script>
```

My controller file:

```
public function meter($value)
 {


    $data=user::where('id',Auth::user()->id)
    ->update(['meter'=>$value]);


  return response()->json([
    'data'=>$value
    ]);
 }
```

Comment: Where you are passing the variable to the view.

Comment: @AmitGupta i want to pass the variable in js where it is written value=10...instead of 10 , i need dynamic value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double curly braces `{{ }}`anywhere in blade template. Example:

```
<script>
    var value = {{ $value }};
    alert(value); //alert is to test if it is working or not
</script>
```

Comment: if string you have to enclose it var value = "{{ $value }}";

Comment: @YaShChaudhary Did you check the value coming from controller?

Comment: @YaShChaudhary Make sure you didn't copy my code. It was just an example. I used `$value`, in your case it might be anything else. As your question it should `$data`. `var value = {{ $data }}`

Comment: @smartrahat yes,I have used {{ $data }} only.

Answer (score 0):

try this package developed by jaffery way @ laracast, it transform php vars to javascript, here is link

https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: i'll surely try it!,Ty!

Answer (score -1):

```
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('j').innerHTML=this.responseText.data;
    }
```

that should do the trick